FFMPEG adding image as footer not working above 3.0.1
I was using FFMPEG Android binaries 3.0.1 (this binding) to add image (as footer) on an existing video, it was working well till Android 13 but now in android 14 the command wont execute and gives return code of 255. Same happening with its original JAVA library.
Command: -y -i 19.mp4 -i footer.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=854:-2[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack",drawtext="arial_reg.ttf:text='965XXXX46':fontcolor=white@0.5:fontsize=25:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -vsync 2 BL_1727179270.mp4

So decided to use ffmpeg-kit (version 6.0 and 4.5) (created bindings). That worked on Android 14 but videos having 25fps only, any video beyond 25 fps gives following errors:
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-2008-g90da43557f'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  built with Android (7284624, based on r416183b) clang version 12.0.5 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee)
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  configuration: --cross-prefix=x86_64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/storage/light/projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-x86_64-lts/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=x86_64 --cpu=x86_64 --cc=x86_64-linux-android21-clang --cxx=x86_64-linux-android21-clang++ --ranlib=llvm-ranlib --strip=llvm-strip --nm=llvm-nm --extra-libs='-L/storage/light/projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-x86_64-lts/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libdav1d --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libavutil      57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libavcodec     59.  7.103 / 59.  7.103
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libavformat    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libavfilter     8.  9.100 /  8.  9.100
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '29.mp4':
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Metadata:
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    major_brand     : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='isom'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    minor_version   : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='512'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    compatible_brands: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='isomiso2avc1mp41'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    encoder         : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Lavf57.83.100'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Duration: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='00:00:30.14'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=', start: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='0.000000'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=', bitrate: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='6902 kb/s'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #0:0'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='[0x1]'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='(und)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=': Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1280x720, 6769 kb/s'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=', '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='30.05 fps, '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='30 tbr, '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='1000k tbn'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (default)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    Metadata:
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='      handler_name    : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='VideoHandler'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='      vendor_id       : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='[0][0][0][0]'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #0:1'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='[0x2]'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='(und)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=': Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (default)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='    Metadata:
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='      handler_name    : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='SoundHandler'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='      vendor_id       : '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='[0][0][0][0]'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Input #1, png_pipe, from 'footer.jpg':
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Duration: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='N/A'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=', bitrate: '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='N/A'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #1:0'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=': Video: png, rgba(pc), 996x326'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=', '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='25 fps, '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='25 tbr, '}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='25 tbn'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Stream mapping:
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> vstack:input0'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (graph 0)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (graph 0)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  drawtext'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (graph 0)'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message=' (aac (native) -> aac (native))'}
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_ERROR, message='[mpeg4 @ 0x7bea56d386c0] timebase 1/1000000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_ERROR, message='Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='[aac @ 0x7bea56d37e40] Qavg: 65536.000
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_WARNING, message='[aac @ 0x7bea56d37e40] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
[FFMPEG-LOG] sessionId=1, level=AV_LOG_INFO, message='Conversion failed!
[FFMPEG-LOG] FFmpeg process exited with state COMPLETED and rc 1.
Any help please.
